# How can I render a highcharts solidgauge with Django?

Tags: javascript, django, highcharts

I would like to display a highcharts solidgauge (https://www.highcharts.com/demo/gauge-solid). For my little app I use Django and Python3.8. But most examples that I found work only for Angular.

**tldr**: I get a red error message from highcharts (No. 17), which states that the requested series type does not exist.

The long story: As I did not know any better way I downloaded four js files (https://code.highcharts.com/modules/solid-gauge.js, https://code.highcharts.com/modules/solid-gauge.src.js, https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js, and https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.src.js). I put them in my Django's static folder and ran manage.py collectstatic.

In my views.py I just tried to replicate the example from the highcharts page, but I do not get it to render. The code looks like this.

```
def landingpage(request):        
   chart = {
       'chart': {
           'type':'solidgauge',
       },
       'title': {'text':'Example gauge'},
       'pane': {
           'center': ['50%', '85%'], 'size': '140%', 'startangle': -90, 'endangle':90, 'background': {
               'backgroundcolor': 'Highcharts.defaultOptions.legend.backgroundColor || \'#EE\'', 'innerRadius': '60%', 'outerRadius': '100%', 'shape': 'arc',
           }
       },
       'exporting': {'enabled': False},
       'tooltip': {'enabled': True},
       'yAxis':{'stops': [
               [0.1, '#55BF3B'], # green
               [0.5, '#DDDF0D'], # yellow
               [0.9, '#DF5353'], # red
           ], 'min':0, 'max':200, 'lineWidth': 0, 'tickWidth': 0, 'minorTickInterval': 'null', 'tickAmount': 2, 'title': {
               'y':-70,
               'text': 'Speed'
           }, 'labels': {
               'y':16
           }
       },
       'credits': {
           'enabled': False
       },
       'plotOptions': {
           'solidgauge': {
               'dataLabels': {
                   'useHTML': True,
                   'borderWidth': 0,
                   'y':6,
               }
           }
       },
       'series': [{
           'name': 'Speed', 'data': [80], 'dataLabels': {
               'format': '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:25px">{y}</span><br/><span style="font-size:12px;opacity:0.4">km/h</span></div>'
           }, 'tooltip': {
               'valueSuffix': ' km/h'
           }
       }]
   }
dump = json.dumps(chart, cls=CustomJsonEncoder)             
gauge = {'chart':dump}
context['chart_example'] = gauge['chart']
return render(request, templ_folder_name + 'landingpage.html', context)

class CustomJsonEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
   def default(self, obj):
       if isinstance(obj, Decimal):
           return float(obj)
       return super(CustomJsonEncoder, self).default(obj)
```

In my template I use this:

```
{% block content %}
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
            <h2 class="page-header">Dashboard</h2>
        <br>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-0 col-md-7 col-md-offset-0">
                <div id="hccontainer"></div>
                    <br>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-0 col-md-4 col-md-offset-0">
                TBD
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        </div>
    {% load static %}
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'highcharts/highcharts.src.js' %}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'highcharts/debugger.js' %}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'highcharts/highcharts-more.js' %}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'highcharts/highcharts-more.src.js' %}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'highcharts/solid-gauge.js' %}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'highcharts/solid-gauge.src.js' %}"></script>
<script>
        Highcharts.chart('hccontainer', {{chart_example|safe}});

        </script>

{% endblock %}
```

Can you give me any advice where my mistake is located?

**Update**:
Actually I have no idea how to work with the developer tools in my FF, but I got a screenshot from what it mentions.

[image: Screenshot from web developer tool]

Comment: Little update: I have now included a column chart and a bullet graph chart (both from highcharts). Those work fine. It's only the solidgauge chart, which still says that this cannot be found.

Comment: So far I have found that the order of script includes like <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'highcharts/modules/bullet.js' %}"></script> is important. Depending on the order I can either load a bulletgraph or the solidgauge that I mentioned above. But I cannot have both. Does anyone have an idea? I tried out a lot of orderings so far.

Answer (score 0):

At least partially I found a solution, but to be honest I do not understand it entirely. I tried several combinations of includes and the one, which seems to work (yet to be tested in detail!) is this:

```html
 <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'highcharts/highcharts.src.js' %}"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'highcharts/modules/bullet.src.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'highcharts/highcharts-more.js' %}"></script>
    <script>
        Highcharts.chart('hccontainer_chart1', {{var1|safe}});
        </script>
    <script>
        Highcharts.chart('hccontainer_chart2', {{chart2|safe}});
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'highcharts/modules/solid-gauge.js' %}"></script>
    <script>
        Highcharts.chart('hccontainer_chart3', {{chart3|safe}});
    </script>
```

I am still confused because it has to be exactly this order. First I wanted to take this order highcharts -> highcharts-more -> bullet -> solidgauge. And furthermore I thought that it would make no difference if I used .js or .src.js, but for some reason it does. Maybe someone who is more experienced with this could explain that to me so that I do not make the same mistakes in the future again.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think that it might solve yours considers - highcharts `solidgauge` module must be initialized after the `highcharts-more` module, because some of the properties are inherited from the `more` module. You can test it on this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gqLhm3cr/

Comment: Dear Sebastian
Thanks! As mentioned in my other answer below I figured out a working order, but still I do not understand why I need the src files in some cases and why the normal js files won't work. Do you have a clue why that is?

Comment: @MDoe to be honest - I don't know - in regular cases (implementing Highcharts on the front without Django, pure JS) don't need to use the src files. I can only guessing that using a Django have an impact on it.

Comment: Okay, then I just have to live with that and perhaps someone else can benefit from this as well. And thanks!